# I have a table 'A' which has 119940377 records and 'a' table is fetching values from 4 different tables based on priority.I want to find count(a)

Tags: sql, oracle, presto

So if below are the records from four tables

| 1st table | 2nd table | 3rd table | 4th table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2. | 3 |
| 2 | 2. | 6. | 4 |
| 3. | 5. | 7. | 10 |

Then A table has 1,2,3 from 1st table,5 from 2nd table,6,7 from third table and 4 and 10 from 4th table.

```
with a as (
select distinct a.id
from  a inner join 
first table b
on a.id=b.id),
b as(
select distinct a.id
from a inner join 
second table b 
on a.id=b.id
except
select * from a),

d as (
  select * from a
  union
  select * from b
),
c as(
select distinct a.id
from a inner join 
third table b 
on a.id=b.id
except
select * from d)

select count(*) as count from a
union
select count(*) as count from b
union 
select count(*)  as count from c
```

Here I get correct count from a and b But from c ,if I execute the first join query alone the count is 78471355 and the count(*) from d alone I get 32579307 as count .When I subtract manually the answer I get is 45892048. But for the query  "select count(*)  as count from c" ,I get the output as 48762978.

Please note I am executing this in presto db and also I have a 4th table too to find the count.I didn't add it since the output from c is wrong.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to count the `id` values in table `a` that also appear in four different tables but comparing the related tables in a priority order; for that, you can use a `CASE` expression to test whether the `id` exists in each related table.

```sql
SELECT table_name,
       COUNT(*) AS num_rows
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM first_table t WHERE a.id = t.id)
         THEN 'first_table'
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM second_table t WHERE a.id = t.id)
         THEN 'second_table'
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM third_table t WHERE a.id = t.id)
         THEN 'third_table'
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM fourth_table t WHERE a.id = t.id)
         THEN 'fourth_table'
         END AS table_name
  FROM   a
)
WHERE  table_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (id) AS
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

CREATE TABLE first_table (id) AS
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE second_table (id) AS
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE third_table (id) AS
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE fourth_table (id) AS
  SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TABLE_NAME | NUM_ROWS |
| --- | --- |
| first_table | 3 |
| fourth_table | 2 |
| second_table | 1 |
| third_table | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D-V6JVUt)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked ,it is very powerful and simpler